# Running multiple docker containers with nginx and adding them SSL

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl, docker-compose

I am trying to upload to production my website, that built using NX, with docker-compose and nginx, and to make it secure by SSL/TLS certificate.

In this NX project, there are 2 apps: frontend, backend.
On the production server (ubuntu VM), which running on 2 docker containers, this is the desired result:

1. Frontend container that is available on https://triprice.com/.
2. Backend container that is available on https://triprice.com/api/ (the /api/ is the gateway for the backend)

(On development enviroment, the backend listen on port 3333, and the client on port 4200)

Those are the following Dockerfiles I have:

builder *Dockerfile* (root of project):

```
FROM node:lts-alpine as builder
ARG NODE_ENV
ARG BUILD_FLAG
WORKDIR /app/builder
COPY . .
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli
RUN npm install -g @nrwl/cli
RUN npm install -g @nx/workspace
RUN npx nx@latest init
RUN npm init nx-workspace
RUN npm install
```

Frontend *Dockerfile*:

```
FROM my-base-image:nx-base AS builder

ARG NODE_ENV
ARG BUILD_FLAG
WORKDIR /app/builder
COPY . .
RUN npx nx build triprice-frontend ${BUILD_FLAG} --verbose

FROM nginx:1.19.2

WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html

COPY --from=builder /app/builder/dist/apps/triprice-frontend ./
COPY --from=builder /app/builder/apps/triprice-frontend/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --from=builder /app/builder/apps/triprice-frontend/cs.crt /etc/ssl/cs.crt
COPY --from=builder /app/builder/apps/triprice-frontend/myserver.key /etc/ssl/myserver.key
```

Backend *Dockerfile*:

```
FROM my-base-image:nx-base AS builder

ARG NODE_ENV
ARG BUILD_FLAG
WORKDIR /app/builder
COPY . .
RUN npx nx build triprice-backend ${BUILD_FLAG} --verbose

FROM my-base-image:nx-base

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app/builder ./
ENV NODE_ENV=$NODE_ENV

CMD ["node", "./dist/apps/triprice-backend/main.js"]
```

Also, I have the *docker-compose.yml* file, that's located in the root of the project:

```
version: "3.8"

networks:
  corp:
    driver: bridge

services:
  triprice-backend:
    container_name: triprice-backend
    build:
      context: ./
      cache_from:
        - my-base-image:nx-base
      dockerfile: ./apps/triprice-backend/Dockerfile
      args:
        NODE_ENV: "production"
        BUILD_FLAG: ""
    image: triprice-backend:nx-triprice-backend-prod
    ports:
      - 3333:3333
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: "production"
      PORT: 3333
    env_file:
      - ./apps/triprice-backend/src/config/.env
    networks:
      - corp
    restart: on-failure

  triprice-frontend:
    container_name: triprice-frontend
    build:
      context: ./
      cache_from:
        - nginx:1.19.2
      dockerfile: ./apps/triprice-frontend/Dockerfile
      args:
        NODE_ENV: "production"
        BUILD_FLAG: ""
    image: triprice-frontend:nx-triprice-frontend-prod
    ports:
      - 443:443
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: "production"
      PORT: 443
    networks:
      - corp
    restart: on-failure
```

And last, I have the *nginx.conf* file, that's loacted in the frontend project (together with the *myserver.key* and *cs.crt* files):

```
user root;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  # Configuration specific to HTTP and affecting all virtual servers

  log_format  main    '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
  sendfile            on;
  tcp_nopush          on;
  tcp_nodelay         on;
  keepalive_timeout   65;
  types_hash_max_size 2048;
  client_max_body_size 50M;
  server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
  include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type        application/octet-stream;

  ##
  # SSL Settings
  ##
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  ##
  # Logging Settings
  ##
  access_log /var/log/nginx/app.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/app.error.log;

  ##
  # Gzip Settings
  ##
  gzip on;
  gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_buffers 16 8k;
  gzip_types   in application/javascript application/x-javascript text/javascript text/xml text/css;
  gzip_vary on;

  # First of all - If tried to get with http://triprice.com -> will redirect
  # to http*s*://triprice.com -> will be secured.
  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name triprice.com www.triprice.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }

  # Next, configure all secured requests to the server of triprice.com
  server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/cs.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/myserver.key;
    ssl_verify_client off;

    # This is the location for the client side.
    location / {
      # This would be the directory where the angular app's static files are stored
      root /usr/share/nginx/html;
      try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    # configuration for processing URIs starting with '/api' (server side)
    location /api {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:3333;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that right now, the server works only on http://triprice.com:3333/api/, instead of https://triprice.com/api.
For example, on route "https://triprice.com/api/users/getAllUsers" - that returns my the page "502 Bad Gateway
I guess the problem is somewhere with the nginx.conf / docker-compose.yml, but can't be sure.

Can someone please help me with this?